# Limit results mysql on where in clausule

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand how i can limit the results to 5 rows for each "post_id".
Example i'm doing this query:

```
$posts_id = array('1','2','3','4');
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE IN post_id, $posts_id LIMIT 5";
```

If i do like that it limit just 5 results of all comments. I Would like get maximum 5 results for each posts without do eager loading and put the query in a foreach.

Any idea?

Comment: Use select top 5 * from ......

Comment: I don't understand what i shall to use?

Comment: $query = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM comments WHERE post_id IN $posts_id";

Comment: means you like query in such way that each post contain maximum of 5 comments?

Comment: Related: [SELECT Where ID in (List of IDs) and limit records of each IDs in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53985995/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of how `IN` works is wrong. Instead you can build your query with [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
//omitting escaping to concentrate on idea:
$posts_id = array('1','2','3','4');
$limit    = 5;
$query = join(' UNION ALL ', array_map(function($id) use ($limit)
{
   return '(SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='.$id.' LIMIT '.$limit.')';
}, $posts_id));
```

Comment: This is an interesting query, but doing UNION is not the same thing to do the same query on a foreach loop in terms of prestation?

Comment: Of course not. Doing query in loop is horrible - because or network & connection overhead per each iteration, while UNION will be fine since it's one query

Comment: Sorry just the last thing, why if i put the `Count('post_id) as n_post` after Select *, it show me just 1 result?

Comment: Because you're not using any grouping column (in `GROUP BY` clause). MySQL will allow that - but, obviously, will group all rows into one (while in normal SQL such mixing of non-group columns and group function isn't valid)

Comment: Really clear explanation thank you, so in this case there is no trick for get the count of the total rows? Sorry but i'm not really good on advanced query

Comment: It is. Do that in separate query, groping by `post_id`. You can, of course, add subquery in each `UNION` part, but _that_ is crap

Comment: Ok! that's make sense. For now i'll let this count separate untill i'll find a better solution cheers!

Comment: Just make your count and then `JOIN` result with `UNION` result - if you want to make it with one query and gain benefit of grouping by `post_id`

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id IN('1','2','3','4') LIMIT 0, 5";
```

Comment: @PaulSinnema its not compulsary to use limit with ordery by only.

Comment: My mistake. It's MySQL not MSSQL

Answer (score -1):

This is the query you should produce in your string if I interpret your question right:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM comments WHERE post_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: I was in MSSQL mode, sorry