# SELECT Where ID in (List of IDs) and limit records of each IDs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have met a situation that I have a list of IDs of a Store table and need to fetch the latest 10 files from each store.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblFiles 
WHERE storeId in (IDs) 
ORDER BY createdDate DESC  
LIMIT 10
```

But, this limits the whole results. I found an answer to a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29257033/5676586). But, the answer recommends using loop for each ID. This results in multiple DB hit.

Another option is to fetch all records and group them in the code. But, this will be heavy if there are large no.of records.

It'll be nice if it can be handled at the query level. Any help will be appreciated.

**NB:** The tables used here are dummy ones.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: MySQL version 5.6.28

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968285/mysql-select-the-last-3-records-per-group/53968566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-MySQL 8.0, the simplest method is probably variables:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = storeId, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := storeId, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select f.*
            from tblfiles f
            where storeId in (IDs) 
            order by storeId, createdDate desc
           ) f cross join
           (select @s := 0, @rn := 0) params
     ) f
where rn <= 10;
```

In MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.3+, you would simply use window functions:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by storeid order by createdDate desc) as seqnum
      from tblfiles f
     ) f
where seqnum <= 10;
```

In older versions of MySQL and MariaDB, the innermost subquery may not be needed.

Comment: This one is nice. And I think you have to use rn instead of @rn in the last where clause.

Comment: @Abhishek . . . Yes.  That was a typo.

Comment: I am almost certain UNIONed queries would be faster than using variables, not as elegant though.

Answer (score 3):

use select in where

```
SELECT * from tblFiles where storeId in (SELECT id from store ORDER BY datefield/id field desc limit 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could workaround it with an UNIONed query, where each subquery searches for a particular id and enforces a LIMIT clause, like :

```
(SELECT * 
FROM tblFiles
WHERE storeId = ?
ORDER BY createdDate DESC
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * 
FROM tblFiles
WHERE storeId = ?
ORDER BY createdDate DESC
LIMIT 10)
...
```

With this solution only one db hit will happen, and you are guarantee to get the LIMIT on a per id basis.  Such a SQL can easily be generated from within php code.

Nb : the maximum allowed of UNIONs in a mysql query is 61.

Comment: This one is nice. But, the query becomes a large one if there are more no.of of IDs (storeId) are there in request.

Comment: @Abhishek : 61 UNIONs is the max. Query is large but easy to generate dynamically...